# How can I know where Debian gets its package sources from?

Tags: debian, opensource-projects

Imagine I have a tool "X". I know it exists in the current Debian distros, so I can find it on https://packages.debian.org.

This site also contains links to the downloadable Debian source packages.

However, where are these source packages coming from? Where is the upstream link from which the source package was originally generated?

Comment: `where these source packages are coming from?` - possibly from `This site also contains links to the downloadable debian source packages.` - just a guess

Comment: On `tracker.debian.org/<pkgname>` you can sometimes (often?) find links to where the maintainer(s) manage the source package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code from which Debian source packages are constructed is tracked in a number of places (not all packages provide all of these):

- `debian/copyright`
- the “Homepage” entry in the control file
- `debian/watch`

Consider [the `libevdev2` package entry](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libevdev2):

- on the right-hand side, the “Homepage” link leads to [the `libevdev` upstream page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev/), which provides links to upstream source code
- the “Developer Information” link leads to [the `libevdev` tracker`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libevdev), and the “browse source code” link there leads to [the Debian source package contents](https://sources.debian.org/src/libevdev/1.13.0%2Bdfsg-1/); from there,

  - [`debian/copyright`](https://sources.debian.org/src/libevdev/1.13.0%2Bdfsg-1/debian/copyright/) points to the upstream page
  - [`debian/watch`](https://sources.debian.org/src/libevdev/1.13.0%2Bdfsg-1/debian/watch/) points to the upstream downloads

Given a source package, extracted locally, with a `debian/watch` file, `uscan --force-download` can be used to retrieve the original source archive (if it is still available).

Note that Debian packages don’t necessarily *have* an upstream source package, even when they aren’t “native” packages — there are quite a few packages whose upstream has disappeared, and the Debian source package is the primary reference.